# Plotly.Express + Pandas multi-index column

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am relatively new to Pandas and Plotly. I will pose my question directly with a MWE of what I want to do:

```
import pandas
import plotly.express as px

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        'n': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4],
        'x': [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
        'y': [1,2,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,3,4,5],
    }
)

mean_df = df.groupby(by=['n']).agg(['mean','std'])

fig = px.scatter(
    mean_df,
    x = ('x','mean'),
    y = ('y','mean'),
    error_y = ('y','std'),
)
fig.show()
```

This code is not doing what I want. The `mean_df` dataframe looks like this:

```
     x              y          
  mean  std      mean       std
n                              
1    0  0.0  1.250000  0.500000
2    1  0.0  2.666667  0.577350
3    2  0.0  3.333333  0.577350
4    3  0.0  4.500000  0.707107
```

I want to plot `x_mean`  vs `y_mean`, with error bars in y, using `plotly.express`. I am not sure how to do this when there are sub-columns in the data frame...

After some research I have found that `mean_df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in mean_df.columns.values]` converts the previous dataframe into

```
   x mean  x std    y mean     y std
n                                   
1       0    0.0  1.250000  0.500000
2       1    0.0  2.666667  0.577350
3       2    0.0  3.333333  0.577350
4       3    0.0  4.500000  0.707107
```

so now I can just do

```
fig = px.scatter(
    mean_df,
    x = 'x mean',
    y = 'y mean',
    error_y = 'y std',
)
```

to obtain the desired result. However, despite this does exactly what I want to do, it does not feel like the way to go...

Answer (score 3):

Similar to your research, flatten the multi-level columns.  You can use index slicing.  This does leave **mean_df** unchanged.

Further updates below.  **Plotly Express** is designed as a simple API.  It is a typical use case to simplify / structure a dataframe fits concept of **x, y, color, hover_name, etc** as columns addressed as strings.  Where multi-index columns are in use, a **series** or **array** can be passed.  Two variations of this demonstrated below.

```
import pandas
import plotly.express as px

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        'n': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4],
        'x': [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
        'y': [1,2,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,3,4,5],
    }
)

mean_df = df.groupby(by=['n']).agg(['mean','std'])

fig = px.scatter(
    mean_df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,"mean"]].droplevel(1,1),
    x = "x",
    y = "y",
)
fig
```

#### using multiple level 1 keys

```
fig = px.scatter(
    mean_df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,"mean"]].droplevel(1,1),
    x = "x",
    y = "y",
    error_y = mean_df.loc[:,("y","std")].values
)
fig.show()
px.scatter(
    x = mean_df.loc[:,("x","mean")],
    y = mean_df.loc[:,("y","mean")],
    error_y = mean_df.loc[:,("y","std")]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will up-vote as it does what I posted in the question. However I was looking for a solution that would not drop columns as I want the `std` ones to plot too. I will update my question to reflect this, sorry.

Comment: updated to cover your question amendment.  IMHO it's good to stay simple, so if there are columns that can't be referenced by a string, pass a series or array instead